# how to group by a column and pick one object ordered by created time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model like below,

```
class MusicData(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    url = models.URLField()
    description = models.TextField()
    age = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                      related_name="music_data",
                                      related_query_name="music_data")
    count = models.IntegerField()
    last_updated = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    playlist = models.ForeignKey(PlayList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                      related_name="music_data",
                                      related_query_name="music_data")
```

I want to get `MusicData` such that group by name, in each group get the one which has latest `created_on` (`created_on` is a `DateTimeField` in `BaseModel`)

suppose say I have following data

```
| Name        | Created On            |
| ----------- | -----------           |
| ABC         | 2019-02-22 1:06:45 AM |
| ABC         | 2019-02-22 1:07:45 AM |
| BAC         | 2019-02-22 1:08:45 AM |
| BAC         | 2019-02-22 1:09:45 AM |
| BAC         | 2019-02-22 1:10:45 AM |
| BBC         | 2019-02-22 1:11:45 AM |
```

The expected output is that

```
| Name        | Created On            |
| ----------- | -----------           |
| ABC         | 2019-02-22 1:07:45 AM |
| BAC         | 2019-02-22 1:10:45 AM |
| BBC         | 2019-02-22 1:11:45 AM |
```

I have written this query, which is working fine for above case

```
models.MusicData.objects.filter(playlist__isnull=True).values(
        "name").annotate(maxdate=Max("created_on"))
```

But, the problem is along with `name` and `created_on` I also need other values like `name`, `url`, `age`, `count`, `playlist__name` etc...

so I have followed this guide : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Came up with this query,

```
models.MusicData.objects.filter(playlist__isnull = True).values(
  "name").annotate(maxdate = Max("created_on")).values("age",
  "name",
  "description",
  "url",
  "count",
  "last_updated",
  "playlist",
  language = F(
    "language__name")
)
```

But, in this case I got duplicate objects, then I inspected sql queries, I figured out this

In the first case, only `GROUP BY name` is there along with joins which is fine

But in the second case, `GROUP BY` has all the columns I have specified in the values, I understand that if we want a column to `SELECT` we must include in `GROUP BY` clause

I even tried to generate a list of `id`s then filter on it, but that also the same case, it aggregates over the whole queryset

```
result = models.MusicData.objects.filter(playlist__isnull=True).values(
        "name").annotate(maxdate=Max("created_on")).values_list("id", flat=True)
# Then filter on this list of id's
```

Anyone help me ???

Note: I am using PostgreSQL database

Comment: Is this a PostgreSQL database? For PostgreSQL it is rather easy, for other db's it can be "challenging"

Comment: yes, it's PostgreSQL @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, I could do this in `PostgreSQL`

```
MusicData.objects.order_by('name', '-created_on').distinct('name')..values(
            "age",
            "name",
            "description",
            "url",
            "since_last_pushed",
            "last_updated",
            language=F("language__name"),
        )
```

which will result me in the following query,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ('name', 'created_on')
  id,
  name,
  url,
  description,
  ... etc,
FROM
  musicdata
ORDER BY name ASC,
         created_on DESC;
```

I wondered if this is a tough question, been more than 2 days, but didn't get any response here make me surprise, I expected answer in hours, did I mistag topics ???